# jQuery Error with 'on' statement Argument of type '"focus"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PlainObject<false | EventHandler<HTMLElement

Tags: jquery, typescript

I am getting the following error:

> TS2345: Argument of type '"focus"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PlainObject void> | EventHandlerBase
>
> ERROR in ./Scripts/Common/kendo.ts

with this jQuery statement in my Typescript file:

```
$(() => {
    $("body").on("focus", ".k-datepicker input, .k-datetimepicker input", (e: Event) => {
        const target: JQuery = $(e.target);
        if (target.closest(".k-widget").hasClass("k-datepicker")) {
            target.data("kendoDatePicker").open();
        } else {
            target.data("kendoDateTimePicker").open("date");
        }
    });
});
```

Looking at the documentation here http://api.jquery.com/on/ there is no version of the on function that even has the event handler as the first parameter. Intellisense in Visual Studio also confirms that the parameters should be correct.

I am using the following versions in my package.json:

```
"@types/jquery": "^3.3.0",
...
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
...
"typescript": "^2.5.0"
```

Any ideas what could cause this error?

Comment: Maybe Kendo expects an old version of jQuery

Comment: It doesn't look like it's Kendo specific. If I change the statement to:     $("body").on("focus", ".blah", (e: Event) => {
        console.log("Hello");
    });
Then I still get the same error.

Comment: I ran into this today when I upgraded by typings definition from jQuery 2.0 to jQuery 3.3. When I revert back to the 2.0 definition then the error goes away. I also noticed that when using 3.3, my VS.NET IntelliSense is choosing the wrong "on()" method signature, which I presume is the source of the error. I'll report back if I manage to sort out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `Event` declaration. jQuery passes an object of type `jQuery.Event` (not `Event`) to your callback.

The solution is to drop the `Event` declaration.

```js
$(() => {
    $("body").on("focus", ".k-datepicker input, .k-datetimepicker input", (e) => {
        const target: JQuery = $(e.target);
        if (target.closest(".k-widget").hasClass("k-datepicker")) {
            target.data("kendoDatePicker").open();
        } else {
            target.data("kendoDateTimePicker").open("date");
        }
    });
});
```